Using italic and bold in a comment
I tried using the italic for a phrase reported in a comment and, inside that phrase, the bold for a single word. All I get was the asterisks used for bolding the word not being parsed as bold markers.
Is there any way to write in italics a phrase, and highlighting in bold the beginning of that phrase? HTML is not allowed in comments, and HTML entities are not parsed in comments.
For example, the first comment I wrote for this question uses the following Markdown.
This is an example of comment using italics and bolding: _**Ei** fu siccome immobile dato il mortal sospiro, stette la spoglia immemore orba di tanto spiro_.

It shows fine in posts, but it is not rendered as expected in comments.

This is an example of comment using italics and bolding: Ei fu siccome immobile dato il mortal sospiro, stette la spoglia immemore orba di tanto spiro.


This is an example of comment using italics and bolding: Ei fu siccome immobile dato il mortal sospiro, stette la spoglia immemore orba di tanto spiro.

Just use an asterisk for italic.
***Ei** fu siccome immobile dato il mortal sospiro, stette la spoglia immemore orba di tanto spiro*

...which looks like this: Ei fu siccome immobile dato il mortal sospiro, stette la spoglia immemore orba di tanto spiro

Doh! I thought it would cause more troubles. :)

La vita è sempre più facile di quanto pensiamo :)
